# Can't access property of array of objects after fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I fetch some JSON, add it to state (becoming an array of objects) and then try to console log the state.  I'm able to successfully console log the array and an object in the array, but when I try to log a property of one of those objects it throws an error.  Why is this?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/db" //test json data
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result.posts);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);
  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    console.log(items); //works
    console.log(items[1]); //works
   //console.log(items[1].id); //Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <h1> Test </h1>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Try to log ```items[1].id``` when you get the response in ```useEffect()```

Comment: When you say `items[1] works` is it prints something? Or `undefined`?

Comment: I can console log "result.posts[0].title" successfully after getting the result, I haven't tried after the setstate (don't know how to).

 Items and items[1] does print successfully in the above code.

Comment: So `items[1].id` throws an error but `items[1].title` works (try to log them one after each other)? I think that the `console.log(items[1]);` before the error returns `undefined` and this is because that maybe `items` is an empty array or it has only one item..

Comment: `items[1]` returns the correct result (an object from the array, which shows the properties).  `items[1].title` and `items[1].id` both give the error "cannot read property (title/id) of undefined".  Console logging the fetch results before the setstate (e.g. result.posts[1].id) works fine.  Data source is (https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/db).

Answer (score 1):

When successfully receiving the result, swapping the order of `setIsLoaded(true)` and `setItems(result.posts)` has solved my problem.  Still am curious as to why the order of the setStates caused the error.